# Sufficient and necessary conditions for |A $\circ$ B| = |A $\times$ B|

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

So I've been asked to give sufficient conditions such that the cardinality of the Cartesian product of A and B is equal to the cardinality of the concatenation of the two languages.

|A $\circ$ B| = |A $\times$ B|

And then I've been asked to prove these conditions are necessary and sufficient using mathematical induction. I am completely confused as to what conditions that the statement would not be true and how you would even use mathematical induction o prove anything about the statement. What conditions are they looking for? And how can I prove them?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: What happens if one of $A$ and $B$ is empty and the other isn’t?

That’s an easy special case. Now assume that $A\ne\varnothing\ne B$. Another special case is the case in which at least one of $A$ and $B$ is infinite, if infinite languages are included in the problem. If they are, and you need more information, let me know.

That brings us to the case in which $A$ and $B$ are finite and non-empty. There is a pretty natural *possible* bijection between $A\circ B$ and $A\times B$ given by $ab\leftrightarrow\langle a,b\rangle$, but it can fail actually to *be* a bijection. Suppose, for instance, that $A=\{\lambda,x\}$ and $B=\{y,xy,xxy\}$. (Here $\lambda$ is the empty word; you may be used to using $\epsilon$ for it.) Then

$$\begin{align*}
A\circ B&=\{\lambda y,\lambda xy,\lambda xxy,xy,xxy,xxxy\}\\
&=\{y,xy,xxy,xxxy\}\;;
\end{align*}$$

it has $4$ elements, not $6$, because some of the composite words are identical. For instance, $(\lambda) (xy)=(x)(y)$. And it isn’t just the presence of $\lambda$ that caused trouble here: the same thing happens if, for instance, $A=B=\{x,xx\}$, so that $A\circ B=\{xx,xxx,xxxx\}$, with only $3$ elements instead of the $4$ in $A\times B$. This is because $(x)(xx)=(xx)(x)$.

Can you isolate from these examples the condition that makes this happen? If you get completely stuck, check the spoiler-protected block below.

> It happens when there are $a_0,a_1\in A$ and $b_0,b_1\in B$ such that $a_0b_0=a_1b_1$ even though $a_0\ne a_1$ and $b_0\ne b_1$. You need to show that if $A$ and $B$ are finite and non-empty, this condition is both necessary and sufficient for $|A\circ B|$ to be different from (and in fact smaller than) $|A\times B|$.

**Added:** I see no reason to use induction here, and no natural way to do so. Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are finite and non-empty. The map

$$f:A\times B\to A\circ B:\langle a,b\rangle\mapsto ab$$

is clearly surjective. It is not hard to show that $f$ is injective (and hence a bijection) if and only if the condition mentioned above does not occur. The desired result then follows from the fact that if $X$ and $Y$ are finite sets, and $g:X\to Y$ is a surjection, then $|X|\ge|Y|$, with equality if and only if $g$ is a bijection. (That last part is *not* true for infinite sets.)

Comment: I figured it out thanks. You really helped. However  I'm still confused as to how to prove the conditions are true using mathematical induction.

Comment: @Carson: I’ve not actually thought that out in detail yet, and I have to go offline for a few hours. I will have some time to think while I’m away, and I’ll try to add something useful to the answer when I get back.

Comment: @Carson: I apologize: life got a bit complicated, and it took longer than I expected to get back to this.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**:

- What can you say about the relation between the carnality of those sets?
- To show that two sets are equal in cardinality, you need to show that there is a bijection between those sets. Think when the obvious choice for a bijection, $f(ab) = (a,b)$ could work.